# Project Not Aware Of Packages After Successful Nuget Package Restore

Tags: c#, git, nuget-package-restore

I am working on a large C# project with other team members. So far the project has been kind of disorganized and every one has had their way of getting their environment up and running for development. For a new member (and future ones) I am trying to document and tighten up our development process. The project is version controlled by git and members are using VS2012, VS2015, and Monodevelop.

The C# projects in our C# solution all have NuGet packages they require. I have in the `.gitignore` file the following:

```
# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# Ignore the actual packages but not the config file for them
**/packages/**/*
!**/packages/repositories.config
# don't ignore build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
```

So when I push from one machine and then clone on the other, I do have a solution with projects contained with in. These projects have `packages.config` files, which is the xml file that contains the name of packages and versions needed.

**Here Is Where My Problem Is**

I tried on a fresh Windows 7 Machine with VS2015 Community Edition to clone the repo, which worked fine. Then there was a prompt to restore the NuGet packages. I did that. I can see that the packages and versions are installed with the NuGet package manager view for the project of interest:
[image]
But in my References of my project they do not appear to be installed:
[image]

**Tried to isolate the problem with a smaller project**

I thought maybe this was odd so I closed the solution and started a new small solution with one small console application project. I added an old version of NUnit to this project and verified that the NuGet package was installed into the `pakcages` directory. Then I closed the solution, and deleted the packages directory. When I opened the solution it realized that the package was not there so I tried to do the restore packages action through the right click on the package menu. This worked just fine.

So I think I must have some other configuration in my big C# project messed up. I don't know if it is installing the packages somewhere else on my system. Any pointers on where to look or what configurations to look at would be helpful and appreciated!

(I have not seen this issue else where, where the package is apparently installed but the project is still unaware of it)

**Update 7/28/2016**
I was having a look at the `nuget.config` file for the solution and it appears that there was a line in there:

```
<add key="repositorypath" value="External\Packages" />
```

Then I found a directory in the same level as my solution file named `External Packages`. I'd like to note that the person who originally set this solution and its projects up is no longer around. So I deleted that directory and the `nuget.config` file. I restarted VS2015 and ran the restore NuGet Packages action. This appeared to restore the packages and made a directory called `packages` where they are stored now. This now mimicks what I was seeing in my small project where I tried to recreate this behavior.

But I am still running into the issue where the NuGet Package Manager says the packages are installed but the 'References' do not show them.

So I am wondering is there a way to config VS to look where these packages are stored for the references?

Comment: I sometimes see the same issue when .NET versions don't match. It's an easy check to make certain they do so I thought I'd through that in the hat.

Comment: Ahh.. Well we are using .NET 4.5 and mono to keep things working cross platform so if that is an issue how does that affect the package restore process?

Comment: Edit your question to add your .csproj file containing your references.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just looked at my .csproj files at the Hint node for the references was indeed pointing to the wrong place. Thankyou! I ended up uninstalling the packages and re installing them and now they all show up in the packages directory at the solution file level and the csproj files all point to those. If you submit an answer I'll accept yours as the correct one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RoberHarvey had the right solution. The problem was in the .csproj files for the projects in my solution. This was all part of a code base that never really had a good way of keeping track of packages and there were failed attempts in the past to fix it. So there were some inconsistencies persisting in my project files. This was remedied by uninstalling and reinstalling the problem packages after deleting the old nuget.config file.